# how to get value using model and scriptlets

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I am creating a table in JSP in which i am displaying some values using hard code. 
i want to display those value using scriptlets and model. Someone help me how to do that?

```
<tr>
             <td>Automobile</td>
             <td>11-JUN-2015</td>
             <td>10-FEB-2016</td>
             <td>Cars and bikes</td>

            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting values from the database:

```
<%rst=stmt.executeQuery("select * from auto_details");%>
```

Sample Html Table:

```
<html>
            <body>
            <center>
                <h2>AutoList</h2>
                <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding ="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>S.No</b></td>
                    <td><b>Date</b></td>
                    <td><b>typeofvichele</.b></td>
                </tr>
                    <%
                    int no=1;
                    while(rst.next()){
                    %>
                    <tr>
                      <td><%=no%></td>
                      <td><%=rst.getString("date")%></td>
                      <td> <%=rst.getString("typeofvichele")%> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <%
                    no++;
        }
        rst.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    %>
                </table>
                </center>
            </body>
        </html>
```